# Display VrPanoView in vr mode

Tags: java, android, android-studio, virtual-reality

Well I am doing a VR application that displays some images. I am using VrPanoramaView.

Any way when I launch the activity to open it in vr mode? Instead of clicking on the button of VR of the panoView

Here's my code:

```
public class MainVrActivity extends Activity
{

    private VrPanoramaView panoWidgetView;
    private ImageLoaderTask backgroundImageLoaderTask;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_vr);

        panoWidgetView = (VrPanoramaView) findViewById(R.id.pano_view);

        loadPanoImage();

    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        panoWidgetView.pauseRendering();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        panoWidgetView.resumeRendering();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Destroy the widget and free memory.
        panoWidgetView.shutdown();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private synchronized void loadPanoImage() {
        ImageLoaderTask task = backgroundImageLoaderTask;
        if (task != null && !task.isCancelled()) {
            // Cancel any task from a previous loading.
            task.cancel(true);
        }

        // pass in the name of the image to load from assets.
        VrPanoramaView.Options viewOptions = new VrPanoramaView.Options();
        viewOptions.inputType = VrPanoramaView.Options.TYPE_STEREO_OVER_UNDER;

        // use the name of the image in the assets/ directory.
        String panoImageName = "Converted.jpg";

        // create the task passing the widget view and call execute to start.
        task = new ImageLoaderTask(panoWidgetView, viewOptions, panoImageName);
        task.execute(getAssets());
        backgroundImageLoaderTask = task;
    }

}

    public class ImageLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<AssetManager, Void, Bitmap> {

    /*We use a WeakReference for the VrPanoramaView since the view could be destroyed while loading the image.
     *A common cause of this is rotating the phone to another orientation. By using a weak reference,
     *the object can be garbage collected immediately instead of waiting for this async task to be destroyed.
     */
    private static final String TAG = "ImageLoaderTask";
    private final String assetName;
    private final WeakReference<VrPanoramaView> viewReference;
    private final VrPanoramaView.Options viewOptions;

    private static WeakReference<Bitmap> lastBitmap = new WeakReference<>(null);
    private static String lastName;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(AssetManager... params) {
        AssetManager assetManager = params[0];

        if (assetName.equals(lastName) && lastBitmap.get() != null) {
            return lastBitmap.get();
        }

        try(InputStream istr = assetManager.open(assetName)) {
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
            lastBitmap = new WeakReference<>(b);
            lastName = assetName;
            return b;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not decode default bitmap: " + e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    //Displaying the image
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        final VrPanoramaView vw = viewReference.get();
        if (vw != null && bitmap != null) {
            vw.loadImageFromBitmap(bitmap, viewOptions);
        }
    }

    public ImageLoaderTask(VrPanoramaView view, VrPanoramaView.Options viewOptions, String assetName) {
        viewReference = new WeakReference<>(view);
        this.viewOptions = viewOptions;
        this.assetName = assetName;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the display mode with `VrWidgetView#setDisplayMode`:

`panoWidgetView.setDisplayMode(VrWidgetView.DisplayMode.FULLSCREEN_STEREO);`